# Can't install MySQL 8 with ONLY Visual Studio 2022 installed on Windows

Tags: mysql, oracle, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022

This is not something unexpected as Oracle/MySQL is always lagging behind the maintstream development. Any alternative way to install it on Windows with ONLY Visual Studio 2022 installed?

I refer to the "Developer Default" and/or "Full" installation option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html

Just to clarify since my post. I have managed to install but not using the "Developer Default" and/or "Full" installation. I have been successfully using the latest MySQL with Visual Studio 2022. So far so good. Only the installation process could be better clarified and handled.

Comment: Please share the error message that your are getting while your are installing mysql v8! Mysql in visual studio are two independent applications, their installations should not interfere with each other!

Answer (score 7):

MySQL isn't supported for Visual Studio 2022 yet.

it's weird and frustrating, to be honest, but if you want to work with MySQL with VS22, you either need to change the Database or go back to VS19.

---

EDIT: (Oct 2022) Finally MySQL is supported for VS22.
I couldn't find the installation guide but I found [this YouTube video](http://youtu.be/HOdJUMlc4ZM).

Comment: That installation process doesn't solve the main issue which is still present. You can't create a TableAdapter at design time on a DataSet, it doesn't recognize the MySQL connector. Accessing a MySQL database (programmatically) hasn't ever been an issue at all.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue, I am obliged to use visual studio 2019 just for connecting to the database, then develop with visual studio 2022. It's the same problem when visual studio 2019 arrived - I had the same issue, therefore the same techniques.
I suggest to not miss the new performance of vs 2022, and keep an eye on the old version.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30591322)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is not yet fully supported in Visual Studio 2022. (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105536)

Thus, I strongly recommend to stick with Visual Studio 2019 for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

So, is this a MySQL/Oracle Issue or is this a Microsoft/Visual Studio Issue? All the answers so far have been obvious:

1. You can't work with MySql if you use Visual Studio 2022
2. You can only use MySql with Visual Studio 2019
3. It may be possible to use VS 2019 to make the connection and then use VS 2022 to develop in

So, Visual Studio 2022 has been out long enough for the connector to be created. Oracle must know that many developers use the latest versions of VS, and Microsoft I am sure understands that many developers use MySql.

Both companies need to understand that not everyone uses Oracle or a Microsoft Database - or Azure, however, those products seem to work just fine right out of the box.

Comment: Oracle has to sell Oracle and MySQL is a competitor. 
Microsoft has to sell MSSQL and MySQL is a competitor.

Comment: You CAN use MySQL with Visual Studio 2022 and I have been using now. So far so good. Only the installation process could be better clarified and handled.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Can you explain the working installation process, please? It can be useful for all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can work with MySQL on VS2022 if you use pure sql manually on code only, like using MySql.Data or MySqlConnector libraries. But that's it, VS 2022 as is cannot connect to DB.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to use Server Explorer to connect to MySQL, then you can install the 64-bit ODBC driver here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Then set up a "User DSN" connection with the ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) app.

Then you'll be able to use Data Source "" and Data Provider ".NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC" to connect to your MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me in VS 2022 ! The ODBC Data Source Administrator (64 bit) is to be found at c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe. For 'data source name' a name like 'mySql odbc connection' seems better to me, for it will appear again when adding a connection in Visual Studio via 'Tools/Connect To Database ...'. 
The Project must target x64, otherwise it will not connect. I tried creating the data source with the 32 bit version of odbcad32.exe under c:\Windows\SysWOW64, but there was no driver for mySql.

Answer (score 2):

Works with Visual Studio 2019. You might have to use that version for a while.